# Responsive Navigation

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, responsive-design

I am trying to create some responsive navigation similar to [Boostrap's](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap), but am having some issues. Here is what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/apautler/eqAZz/. It may be difficult to tell in the example, but the navigation disappears when you go from small to large with the screen. I know the reason for this is that the jQuery is checking if the screen size is under 992px at load. If it is, it hides the navigation. Then when you enlarge the page the navigation is still hidden. I need to somehow have it reassess as the page resizes. I think there is a jQuery resize() funciton, but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

I am also open to starting over if there is a better way to build it altogether. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you could trigger the window resize event, so the size gets calculated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to use CSS3 [Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

```
@media all and (max-width:500px) { 
     .navigation {display:none;}
}
```

Comment: That's a good point. I guess because I had to use jQuery for the slide toggle, I was thinking that I should use it for the hiding of the nav. I probably could just use display: none with media queries, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/will/eqAZz/2/embedded/result/

I'm not sure why you couldn't get it working. In JS fiddle, you'll have to look at the full screen version though.

That said, you should look into media queries using CSS. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

No javascript required!

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
if ($(window).width() < 992) {
$('#nav-primary').hide();
}
else {
$('#nav-primary').show();
}
});
```

works

Answer (score 0):

here's a basic window resize handler

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var hideShow=($(window).width() < 992 ) ? 'hide' :'show';
    $('#nav')[hideShow]();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial, Link: http://hightechnology.in/how-to-create-responsive-menu-2/

Demo is their and you can download code too.